# want to check value of a particular node exists or not in Java

Tags: java, android

My XML file as follows:

```
   <Data>
     <goals1>
        <OwnerId>51</OwnerId>
        <PassionId>305</PassionId>
        <GoalId>232</GoalId>
        <goalname>sdjhjhd</goalname>
     </goals1>
     <goals1>
      <OwnerId>51</OwnerId>
      <PassionId>291,305</PassionId>
      <GoalId>231</GoalId>
      <goalname>hfhjkjk</goalname>
    </goals1>
    <goals1>
      <OwnerId>51</OwnerId>
      <PassionId>308</PassionId>
      <GoalId></GoalId>
      <goalname>hfhjkjk</goalname>
    </goals1>
  <Data>
```

want to check a goal id exists under particular passion id or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 DocumentBuilder db=Null;
   Document doc = null;
```

In your XML Read function:

```
try {

       db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
       } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
                            //Logger.getLogger(JavaTestApps.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,          null, ex);

                        }



                        InputSource is = new InputSource();
                        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(yourxmlstring));

                        try {
                            doc = db.parse(is);
                        } catch (SAXException ex) {
                            //Logger.getLogger(this.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                          // Logger.getLogger(this.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }


                        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("mainTagofXML");
                      //  System.out.println(nodes.getLength());

                        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {

                            Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
                            System.out.println("Hello : "+element);
                            NodeList name = element.getElementsByTagName("yourItem");
                                           Element line = (Element) name.item(0);

                           ---  check element is exsists

                                          }
```

Hope this help